# File activity in a Document Library/List Item

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-info-panel

The modern SharePoint has the [details pane](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/File-activity-in-a-document-library-6105ecda-1dd0-4f6f-9542-102bf5c0ffe0) on the right hand side of the screen. When you are in a Document Library or List and you click that little i, if there is not item selected, you will get the Recent Activity pane.

Is there a way (OOTB or custom) that we can remove/hide that ***Recent Activity*** activities?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Recent Activity is built-in feature in SharePoint Online. To hide the Recent Activity on the details pane, you may need scripts.

[Customizing the "modern" experiences in SharePoint Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/modern-experience-customizations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

An alternative, switch the experience from modern to classic.